# Connection to firefox fails when applying runApp() from shiny in R

Tags: command-line, 18.04, browser, r

I'm doing the shiny tutorial like explained on https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/

At a certain point I have to run the example app.
The example app is stored in the folder */usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/01_hello* and I want to run it within the terminal. So I type in

```
sudo -i R  # entering my password so that R is being started
library(shiny)
runApp("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/01_hello")
```

but it doesn't work.

My console gives me the following error message:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3530 

Running Firefox as root in a
regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by tobias.) 

Running
Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. 
($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by
tobias.) 

Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not
supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is
owned by tobias.) 

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks:not found 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found 
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:3530'
```

Here [Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by radix.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037052/running-firefox-as-root-in-a-regular-users-session-is-not-supported-xauthori) I found the firefox issue but without relation to R...

My aim is after entering `runApp()` that firefox opens respectively opens a new tab and shows the shiny app so that I can interact with it.

Also I have to say, that I'm new to ubuntu - so keep that in mind when answering my question. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiny uses TCP ports from high range (>1024), so you do not need `sudo` here.

Execute all commands as your ordinary user, which has access to Xorg:

```
R
library(shiny)
runApp("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/01_hello")
```