# Opening firefox as root

Tags: command-line, firefox, vmware

I cannot use `firefox &` to open Firefox, since you are not supposed to run it in root.
This is for a class I am taking on vulnerabilites, which is why I am even attempting this.

I resorted to the following guide to be able to run firefox as root, and it worked:
[Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($XAUTHORITY is /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority which is owned by radix.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037052/running-firefox-as-root-in-a-regular-users-session-is-not-supported-xauthori?newreg=54dc0ac5ee1b4ddd8268965d5ce7acfb)

But when I have done this, it leaves me without control of the CLI. How can I regain control of the CLI to type in the next command, when I normally would have had control by using the '&' sign?

Comment: Provide full detail here on how you launch firefox in your terminal. Just typing "firefox &" indeed should launch it in the background and immediately release the prompt.

Comment: if ReGaining Terminal Control Is The Main Issue, use `firefox &disown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem, you just follow the tutorial I linked, but also add an & sign on the end:

```
XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority sudo firefox &
```